# FQL Statement must contain indexable column - My query does but it says that it doesn't

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get link information from Facebook and I can't get it to work without thw following error:

> Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an
>   indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked
>   from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql

Column `url` is an indexable column as [stated on this information page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/)

Here's a link to the query that I am using in the Graph Explorer:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%22

The table link_stat is public too.

Has anyone else experience this?  Why does it say that I'm not using an indexable column when I am - I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the FQL tab rather than the explorer tab

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20click_count%2C%20url%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%3D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%22

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It was really doing my head in that :)